# Created my own data type in Linux Kernel. Now how do I use it?

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve the producer consumer problem by creating my own semaphore in the Linux kernel.  I did that in sys.c by creating a struct:

```
struct my_sem
{
    int value;
    struct task_struct *pro[25];
};
```

Now when im in my program and try to create this semaphore:

```
my_sem mutex1;
```

I get an error that says "my_sem undeclared"

I included unistd.h and compiled in gcc with the -i option.  I feel like there's something else i'm missing.

Thank You.

Comment: You should read a basic book about C programming before writing things that go in the Linux kernel. (producer / consumer in the Linux kernel, really?) When you declare a `struct` type in C you always have to use the keyword `struct` with the *tag* name. Or you have to work a bit more and also declare a `typedef` for the name.

Comment: Ok so I have to declare it as a struct even though it is in the linuex kernel?

Comment: why do you think that the rules of the C language would change because it is "in the Linux kernel"? In any case, I am not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: It is a very poor programming practice to place your user code anywhere inside the kernel.   BTW: how did you place anything inside the kernel without having to re-compile the kernel?

Comment: This question is roughly equivalent to "I'm new to using a scalpel, but how do I perform brain surgery on someone?" Please, please stop what you are doing and read books on the Linux kernel design to understand what should and should not be done in kernel-space. Simultaneously, read books on C in general and especially synchronization constructs. In your case, you should used a POSIX semaphore (http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview). Never role your own when someone with a lifetime of experience in the field has already done it for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you make your own struct and want to use it you have to say:

```
struct my_sem mutex1;
```

To make it look nicer, use typedef:

```
struct my_sem
{
    int value;
    struct task_struct *pro[25];
};
typedef struct my_sem my_sem;
```

The first `struct my_sem` is what you have to say every time you want to make a new variable of type my_sem. the second `my_sem` is what you can use as a simplification. everytime you say `my_sem` the compiler will use `struct my_sem`.

Now your piece of code

```
my_sem mutex1;
```

works.

Comment: while this answer is informative, it does not address the fact the (per the OP) struct definition is only in existence inside the kernel.  Wouldn't there need to be a related header file that contains this struct definition and some code within the kernel to process that struct definition?

Comment: Please do not encourage questions like this by giving answers that allow the OP to unwittingly proceed with what is obviously a terrible idea.